# Use C preprocessor macros (just the constants) as Python variables

Tags: python, c-preprocessor

I am writing a Python code which needs to interoperate with C code which I also wrote. In C I have a section like

```
#define FOO 23    // whatever
#define BAR 54.3  // something else
```

I want to use these in python (as regular variables is fine). I am not finding anything in my web searches, and I could easily write a parser myself, but.... I can't believe I am the first one with such a need. PyPreprocessor comes close, but not exactly.

Is there a obvious way to do so which I am missing?

Comment: Add an attribute to a module with given value

Comment: If you are mixing C and Python, this is done in the C code of a *builtin* module. And when you only want to use some constants in Python, the common way is to declare them *by hand* inside a module. I have never found (nor even search to be honest) a *magic tool* that would extract constants from a C header or source file to build a Python source file.

Comment: What's you're missing is that parsing this in Python would be trivial.

Comment: @martineau I wrote that I could **easily** write a parser myself...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I am not really "mixing" the different programming languages: the C code produces some data which is then sent (via USB, but it does not really matter) to another device where the python code needs to interpret the data. Hence Python needs those constants. Because of DRY I really do not want to declare them by hand. Look like I'll do a parser

Comment: OK…in that case then the point you're missing must be that it's so easy, no one has ever bothered to put in it a package and publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's overkill, but you could use parser from [dissect.cstruct](https://pypi.org/project/dissect.cstruct/) module.

It currently supports plain preprocessor defines and simple expressions like `#define TWO (ONE+1)` , but
don't support conditionals like `#if` and `#ifdef`.

Code example

```
from dissect.cstruct import cstruct    

defs_str = """
#define FOO 23    // whatever
#define BAR 54.3  // something else
"""

c = cstruct()
c.load(defs_str)
print(c.consts)  # => {'FOO': 23, 'BAR': 54.3}
print(c.FOO)     # => 23
print(c.BAR)     # => 54.3
```

Comment: This is perfect! I knew something like it must have existed, wonder why it was not more widely known!